# SonarQube takes only on csproj to do the anlyse from SLN

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I want to run the SonarQube analyse on my sln files meaning, all the csproj included into that file.
Apparently I am missing one point in the configuration because my scanner will only takes one csproj (always the same)

This is how I use my command line

```
E:\SonarQube\bin\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe  begin /k:"MySuperProjectKey" /n:"MySuperName" /v:"1.0"
```

Then I am doing the build with msbuild tools (no visual studio involved)

```
'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:Rebuild  /p:Configuration=dev MySuperVSProjectWithPlentyOfCSPROJ.sln"'
```

Then ending it normaly

```
"E:\SonarQube\bin\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end"
```

At the end of the day there is only one C# sharelibrary project analysed on my SonarQube website instead of 10 or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use the `SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe` instead of the `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe`
All my csproj are now on my dashboard.

Comment: `SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe` and `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe` should be functionally equivalent if they come from the same release.

Comment: @Valeri If they are functionally equivalent why use different names?

Comment: @JeroenHeier we are trying to implement a new naming scheme and in order to be backwards compatible with existing scripts and builds that hardcoded old file names we kept the old ones.

Comment: I did the change because I saw a message telling me that the other one will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 0):

you can exclude your unnecessary csproj file from sonarqube scanning. the following may helpfull to you to do that

```
 <!-- in .csproj -->
 <PropertyGroup>
 <!-- Exclude the project from analysis -->
 <SonarQubeExclude>true</SonarQubeExclude>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I want all of them, not only one. Sorry If i was not clear.